# как создать csv файл в определенной директории, если его имя заранее неизвестно

Tags: python, база-данных, csv

В моей программе пользователь проходит регистрацию, и в этот момент должен создаваться csv файл с названием по его id из БД, куда заносятся его данные. В этот csv файл в этот же момент должен быть занесен его изначальный вес, который он укажет при регистрации, а позже нужно будет добавлять в этот csv файл новые данные о весе, которые введет пользователь. Проблема в том, что id заранее неизвестно, а еще мне нужно создавать этот csv в отдельной папке этого проекта, поэтому я не знаю, как правильно указать ссылку на месторасположение файла.

```
k = id + '.csv' # id получен из БД
# r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\csv' это ссылка на папку csv файлов
with open(k, mode='w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(ves) # вес ввел пользователь
```

Comment: Можете назвать tmp, а потом переименовать как хотите.

Comment: @СергейКох то есть сначала создавать файл tmp, а после переименовывать его?

Comment: С любым именем, которое вам подойдет.

Comment: @СергейКох а как можно переименовать файл через  python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html?highlight=rename#os.rename